# Aggregate fields selectively based on MAX(value)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very large union query that produces the following results:

```
p_id       title_id        title        is_live

1          37              TITANIC      1
2          37              TITANIC      0

3          41              AVATAR       0
4          41              AVATAR       0

5          44              HOME ALONE   0

6          11              COMPUTE      1
7          11              COMPUTE      1
8          11              COMPUTE      1
```

From this result, I want to aggregate it so that I get at least one of each title (title_id), but all titles with `is_live` = True. (In other words, for each `title_id`, I want to get exactly one result if MAX(is_live)=0, but all results if MAX(is_live)=1 for that `title_id`.) Here's an example of the result set that I want, with an explanation for each title:

```
p_id       title_id        title        is_live

1          37              TITANIC      1 // live one for titanic

3          41              AVATAR       0 # at least one of each title (which one doesn't matter)

5          44              HOME ALONE   0 /* at least one of each title */

6          11              COMPUTE      1 // keep all, since all are live
7          11              COMPUTE      1
8          11              COMPUTE      1
```

The query that I have so far is along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    80-line UNION query
) d
GROUP BY
  d.title_id
```

But this of course isn't accurate enough and is more an outline. How would I do the above?

Here is a SQLFiddle for the question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/739a36/2/0

Comment: additionally, how do I leave 'comment text' in a line? `#` or `//` doesn't work in the above annotations.

Comment: `#`, `-- `, and `/**/` are the comment operators in MySQL, with `/**/` being a block comment. So `#` should work unless you are commenting something that breaks the query.

Comment: @yanman1234 looks like `/* text */ ` is the only one that works -- see my text in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with variables:

```
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             (@rn := if(@t = title, @rn + 1,
                        if(@t := title, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (<your query here>) q cross join
           (select @t := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by title, is_live desc
     ) q
where is_live = 1 or rn = 1;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/739a36/14) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work -- I still get some entries where I have two items where `is_live`=1 and `is_live`=0 (like the example above for TITANIC, both would show in your query. I set up a SQL fiddle -- you can test it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/739a36/2/0.

Comment: added a SQLFiddle to the question as well.

Comment: @David542 . . . Right idea.  Wrong code.  I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it using `union all`, first selecting all `is_live` true rows and selecting one false `is_live` row for the title_id's not previously selected.

```
select *
from `a`
where is_live
union all
select max(p_id),title_id,max(title),max(is_live)
from `a` a1
where not is_live 
and not exists (select 1 from `a` a2 
                where a1.title_id=a2.title_id and a2.is_live)
group by title_id
```

Comment: note that this misses the title "Avatar" though (which has 0 is_live items).

Comment: i see it isn't in the fiddle provided..may be you missed it in sample data.

Comment: it is. See image below -- http://imgur.com/tQmmlEV. Here's a link as well -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/739a36/12

Comment: (3, 41, 'AVATAR', 0), (4, 41, 'AVATAR', 0), (5, 41, 'HOME ALONE', 0), there are 3 rows (in the fiddle) with title_id 41 with different names, one of the rows should have title_id 44 per the sample shown in question.

Comment: oh, I see. Got it. I fixed the input data and your query works. Thanks.